# ldap allows only one login per user id

Tags: ldap, login

i am newbie with openldap, i would like to store user name and password a in ldap system. How can i ensure that each login can be only login on one machine at any one time?

"my application should limit the number of user sessions to one"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of the Operating System (typically PAM if you are talking Linux), not the LDAP service.

Please tell us what O/S and service you are trying to limit.

Answer (score 1):

OpenLDAP, by itself, isn't going to do that.  It is a read-optimized database for storing metadata.

You may be able to craft something that would work though.  I would look to PAM, but you may be able to do something with just a login script that updates an attribute that says if you are logged in or not.

This will likely be an administrative nightmare though, as people who don't logout correctly will never get the flag reset and you'll have to manually do it.  Or have another process that cleans up stale logins.

Answer (score 0):

That's not traditionally the job of the directory service, and there's no built-in mechanism in OpenLDAP to do what you're trying to do.

You need to define what you mean by "logged-in" (SSH session, "mapped" "drive" with the SMB protocol, HTTP-based access to an application, etc) first, then configure either built-in functionality in the operating system (PAM, for example) or application you're using to limit the number of user sessions, or have something written to do what you want.

Comment: i would choose 'application you're using to limit the number of user sessions'